# Add conditions to dependencys in CakePHP models? (or have dependent on multiple things together)

Tags: php, cakephp, dependencies, cakephp-1.3, conditional-statements

A `User` submits an `Upload` (like an image) of an `Event` to the website.

If EITHER the User OR the Event get deleted, the image should stay - but if BOTH the User AND the Event get deleted, the Upload should also be deleted.

Can this be done by setting CakePHP's `dependent` in the model?  Can it be dependent on a combination of both things?  Or - can I add conditions to the `'dependent'=>true` ?

For example:

```
var User = array(
    'Upload' => array(
        'dependent' => true,
        //can I set a condition here? Or pass array w/ conditions to line above?
    ),
);
```

I'm fairly new to Cake, so if I've missed the boat - ie if there's another better way to do this, feel free to let me know.

My only thought so far is to just have it NOT dependent, and run the delete query myself w/ all needed conditions - but was hoping CakePHP would have something like this built in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it would probably be best to do a bit of a check in afterDelete(), eg:

```
User::afterDelete(){
// if !$this->Event->find(...conditions...); delete the image
}

Event::afterDelete(){
// if !$this->User->find(...conditions...); delete the image
}
```

you could also use beforeDelete() with a check in a similar way, and if the conditions are met set 'dependent' dynamically through the relations

there is no way to set conditions on the 'dependent' option of the params

Comment: Would this be in the model?  Can you add a link(s) to where there is information about this?  (Thanks VERY much)

Comment: beforeDelete and afterDelete are model callbacks, so yes in the model.http://book.cakephp.org/view/1048/Callback-Methods

Answer (score 0):

When calling the delete method in your model, set the second option to true.

Use BeforeDelete/AfterDelete methods in your model in conjunction with http://book.cakephp.org/view/1036/delete

```
delete(int $id = null, boolean $cascade = true);
```

Deletes the record identified by $id. By default, also deletes records dependent on the record specified to be deleted.

For example, when deleting a User record that is tied to many Recipe records (User 'hasMany' or 'hasAndBelongsToMany' Recipes):

```
if $cascade is set to true, the related Recipe records are also deleted if the models dependent-value is set to true.
if $cascade is set to false, the Recipe records will remain after the User has been deleted.
```

Comment: I don't think you full understood/read the question.  I appreciate your attempt though.